# How to call parameterized function from the dll in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, dll, dllimport, visual-c++-2008

I have visual c++ `.dll` file which I have added as the reference in VB.Net project. That created `Interop.mydlllib.dll`.

Now I want to use the function having three parameters from `dll` inside my one function.

How to call this VC++ dll function inside my VB.Net function.

I'm very new to VB.Net, so any help is appreciated... :)

(I searched on the internet and tried the ways suggested there...but still error ... :( )

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: It was some editor error .... :( .... I did everything correct but this editor is pretty complex to handle for linux person :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've referenced a Dll inside a VB project, then you will simply need to call it from it's namespace.

I.e. inside the C++ project there will be something (Probably the application/dll name) that it will register itself under.

From here, you simply need to start typing for intellisense to kick in and you'll see the name of your Dll listed in the dropdown list. Select that name and you should see your function name that you'll be able to call.